# ilink64 Error Fatal: Unable to open file 'VCL.VIRTUALIMAGELIST.O'

Tags: linker, 64-bit, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-12-athens

I migrated an `*.exe` project from Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3 Rio to 12 Athens.

In 32-bit, all works fine, I can compile and link at 32-bit with no problem.

In 64-bit, I can only compile without error, but I get a fatal error in linking:

> [ilink64 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'VCL.VIRTUALIMAGELIST.O'

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

I have "link with runtime packages" set to true.

Comment: "*I can compile and link at 32-bit **and at 64-bit** with no problem. In 64-bit ... I get a fatal error in linking*" - kind of contradictory statements, don't you think? Either it works in 64bit, or it doesn't work, it can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had a similar problem, I fixed it by making sure that $(BDSLIB)\win64\release is the first entry in the 64 bit library path.

You can do this at Tools | Options | Language | C++ | Paths and Directories or on a project by project basis in the project's settings.

Andy